# XFCE4 in a Docker container on Windows with vcxsrv - setup for multiple screens

Tags: docker, x11, desktop, xfce, xrandr

I am currently investigating the possibilities of running a Desktop Environment(XFCE4) in a Docker container. The purpose would be creation of an isolated development environment for VHDL which would be easy to install and setup by students.

I base my XFCE4 image on the X11docker dockerfiles and so far it works in a single window mode. What I would like to achieve is being able to work with this container having multiple screens created by vcxsrv. Running of the X server is ok being left to be done by the user since it depends on personal preference and screen count. I wonder how could I start XFCE4 and having it automatically spawn a virtual desktop spanning all screens and divide it.

My guess was using xrandr and Arandr to achieve that but somehow my container didn't recognized multiple screens on my X Display. Even though everything I have been doing in the container was actually mirrored to all screens.

I am starting the X server with the following command:

```powershell
.\vcxsrv.exe -wgl -keyhook +xinerama -ac -screen 0 @1 -screen 1 @2 -screen 2 @3 -screen 3 @4
```

This is the output I get from xrandr:

```bash
root@docker-desktop:/# xrandr --listactivemonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*default 1920/503x1017/264+0+0  default
root@docker-desktop:/# xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*default 1920/503x1017/264+0+0  default
root@docker-desktop:/# xrandr --prop        
Screen 0: minimum 0 x 0, current 1920 x 1017, maximum 32767 x 32767
default connected primary 1920x1017+0+0 503mm x 264mm
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
   1920x1017      0.00*
```

My Dockerfile:

```docker
FROM debian:buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-mark hold iptables && \
    env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      dbus-x11 \
      xdg-utils \
      x11-utils \
    && env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      gtk2-engines-xfce \
      gtk3-engines-xfce \
      libxfce4ui-utils \
      thunar \
      xfce4-session \
      xfce4-settings \
      xfdesktop4 \
      xfwm4 \
      xfce4-terminal \
      arandr \
    && env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      libgtk-3-bin \
      mousepad \
    && env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      libxv1 \
    && sed -i 's%<property name="ThemeName" type="string" value="Xfce"/>%<property name="ThemeName" type="string" value="Raleigh"/>%' /etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xsettings.xml \
    && env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get remove -y --no-install-recommends xdg-utils

CMD ["startxfce4"]
```

From my understanding vcxsrv creates an X display. An X display can contain multiple screens. Why can't the software in my Docker container recognize the other screens in the display? What am I missing?

Comment: If you're looking for a full desktop environment, a virtual machine will be a better match (and probably much easier to set up and run).

Comment: Yes normally that's true and this is a backup solution we do nevertheless. The idea was that a docker container would waste much less space on disk than with a virtual machine. Furthermore the virtualization layer of a VM with virtual CPUs limits the capabilities of the VM by giving it only 2 CPUs and 2 GB of memory for example. With a docker container I imagine that resource sharing would be better.